# Can’t mount mapper device at boot on Debian

Tags: mount, automounting, device-mapper

My `/etc/fstab` file is the following:

```
proc    /proc   proc    defaults       0       0
/dev/root       /       ext4    rw,errors=remount-ro    0       1
tmpfs   /dev/shm        tmpfs   mode=0777       0       0
tmpfs   /tmp    tmpfs   mode=1777,size=128M     0       0
tmpfs   /run    tmpfs   mode=0755,nosuid,nodev  0       0
sysfs   /sys    sysfs   defaults        0       0

# Add swap
#/dev/MyVolGroup/swap   none    swap    sw      0       0

/dev/mapper/MyVolGroup-data     /mnt/data       ext4    defaults         0       0
```

But the last device won’t mount at boot saying

> Timed out waiting for device /dev/mapper/MyVolGroup-data

But once the system is booted and I do **`mount -a`** it mounts fine

Same goes for swap.

I have tried to add `_netdev` option and then it tries to mount later but still can’t mount.

How can I make those two mounted at boot?

`pvs` output:

```
root@wdmc:~# pvs
  PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/dm-0  MyVolGroup lvm2 a--  <3.64t 3.63t
```

`blkid` output:

```
root@wdmc:~# blkid
/dev/mtdblock5: UUID="2038344949" TYPE="ubi"
/dev/mtdblock6: UUID="3233018442" TYPE="ubi"
/dev/mtdblock7: UUID="1869220897" TYPE="ubi"
/dev/md0: UUID="0dea8221-e8b4-49b3-9599-df5b5b15dba7" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
/dev/sda: UUID="f073ddc5-796f-1ab7-5538-43e0ea150f90" UUID_SUB="94ac9e96-72b0-56e9-2b5e-940b8fd7a692" LABEL="(none):0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/mapper/cryptroot: UUID="TmCwwm-dScT-kBwA-4HL1-W0DX-5z3R-DzoKZM" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/MyVolGroup-swap: UUID="7add317b-6d28-4fce-9a35-0b3a2d989236" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/MyVolGroup-root: UUID="37592b11-f46b-4c07-ae3e-1011e2d3229c" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/MyVolGroup-data: UUID="fa084115-e022-4fe4-a2d1-4785a02ab9d7" TYPE="ext4"
```

Comment: Are you able to view the UUID of `MyVolGroup-data`?

Comment: What kind of device contains your LVM volume group `MyVolGroup`? Please add the output of the `pvs` command to the question. And which version of Debian are you using?

Comment: @Rayleigh Yes, but by `blkid` only

Comment: @telcoM Ok, updated the question with `pvs` output. It is external storage device with embedded system

Comment: It appears to me like the kind of problem that can be fixed by using `fsck`. Am not sure though, so I'll this one to the professionals

Comment: You said it's an external device ... but, when your Linux attempt to mount /dev/mapper/MyVolGroup-data , is the external interface use by your device ready ?

Comment: Looks like `/dev/dm-0` is probably `/dev/mapper/cryptroot`, which is a LVM2 member (that is, a PV) which is apparently on top of `/dev/md0` which is software RAID, which is on top of... whatever. The initramfs will take care of the activation of the root LV (only), but since the problem LV is on the same VG that has just one PV, if the root LV is accessible then the data LV should be ready to activate also... perhaps it's just a problem of things happening in the wrong order because of insufficient dependencies between systemd services. I'll think about this some more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since those two devices are not critical for system boot, don’t bother to add those in `/etc/fstab` and slow down your system startup. Instead, add those to your `rc.local` so it gets mounted after all you drives are ready.

rc.local:

```
swapon /dev/mapper/MyVolGroup-swap
mount /dev/mapper/MyVolGroup-data /mnt/data
```